# Getting this error on my flutter app while triggering SMS--[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null

Tags: flutter, firebase, mobile, sms

[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:18.0.1'

Getting above error while triggering from flutter app

Not sure where to make the change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037392/sms-verification-code-request-failed-unknown-status-code-17093-null-firebase-p  ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.